Why would villages be situated in "compounds?"
Rather than lots of different individual houses, a village could be a single building for everyone. For a real world example, consider Whittier, Alaska.

Whittier, Alaska, is a sleepy town on the west side of Prince William Sound, tucked between picturesque mountains. But if you're picturing a small huddle of houses, think again.
Instead, on the edge of town, there stands a 14-story building called Begich Towers — a former Army barracks, resembling an aging hotel, where most of the town's 200 residents live. (Source)

If people pool their resources, you could have a "compound" with many rooms, almost like a very modest castle. It would allow better protection and temperature control. My world has a pre-industrial tech level.
Why would villages develop this way?

You seem to have answered your own question: "people pool their resources [....] better protection and temperature control." - doing that then asking for alternatives would seem to constitute brainstorming. Can you perhaps add the reason that you've dismissed those as insufficient and tell us more about what would work as an answer? (To avoid closure)

Whittier, Alaska isn't unique. Viking communities lived in a single longhouse and if I remember correctly, some Polynesian and/or tropical Asian cultures lived in single, communal houses. As with all things, thee are pros and cons (economics vs. lack of privacy, security vs. independence). Unfortunately, "why does X?" questions are (like this one) usually too opinion-based. Please remember we're not a free research service. What has your research failed to teach you? What specific problem are you trying to solve?

I understood for most of those cultures it was two or three 'houses' rather than one? The women's and the mens usually being separate edifices, at least for the singletons, and when it comes to the vikings I thought that the long house was more normally for the chiefs men, for feasts and a meeting hall rather than the single and only home for the entire village, or are those Hollywood lenses in my glasses?

Why do people do anything? These questions where people fish for ideas aren't appropriate for this site. Literally every answer is equally valid.

the usual problem with this idea, which actually was attempted countless times since the Neolithic, is that it vastly increases the chance of catastrophic fire.  In a coupound, one house-fire can instantly spread to every other household, making attempts at fire-fighting next to impossible. Traditional villages were thus always built so that huts were far enough apart to keep a stray spark from spreading between them, with the smithy, potter's furnace and sometimes the kitchens being far away in a separate hut..

Flip the question around
Most villages in the real world have not been made up of a single building.  Let's look at some of the reasons why that is the case and the problems you would have to overcome in order for it to be otherwise.

Fire risk.  Historically, wood and other plant-based materials have been used for the construction of the majority of buildings.  Even stone buildings tend to have wooden frames and floors.  Put this together with the requirement to use fire for cooking prior to the introduction of electricity and it is unsurprising that buildings have burned down throughout history.  If each family is in its own building then the loss of one building means either the loss of one family or a small number of survivors who need to stay in other families' homes - the village survives either way.  If the building is the village, then that's the end of the village and probably all the villagers, especially in a very cold climate.
Dispersion of food production.  In a pre-industrial situation 90+% of the entire population will be involved in food/textile production.  At the village level, this would be 95-100%, since the majority of secondary/tertiary industry would occur in the towns and cities rather than villages.  Which means that villagers will need to be tending fields and flocks.  Putting everyone in the same building makes everyone walk further to work each day.  (See this article for a good overview of patterns of land use around a population centre.)  The only situation where this might make some sense would be a mining village where the main economic activity is mining and food is traded for whatever is mined.  However, pre-industrial mining was a really miserable, dangerous occupation that was only undertaken by a minority of the population.
Expansion / repair issues.  What happens when something needs to be fixed in the middle of the building?  What happens when more space is needed?  In a "normal" village, the answers will affect one building at a time.  In a one-building-village, repairs will probably make surrounding apartments inaccessible/unusable for a time, while expansion will be a nightmare, as anyone who has lived/worked in a building undergoing renovations will know.  Note that, as per the article above, space in the centre of a village is valuable and used - expanding the building will displace some other activity that needed that space.  (Also consider that your example of a 14-storey building is outright impossible for a pre-industrial village and even a 2+ storey building makes maintenance activities such as thatching more difficult.)
Hygiene.  Cramming lots of people and their animals closely together creates a massive disease risk and immense challenges for bringing in fresh water and disposing of human and animal waste.  Castles could manage this somewhat with servants, paid for with the wealth taxed from the lands they controlled.  (Besieged castles and fortified towns still routinely suffered from disease outbreaks.)  Villages don't have the surplus wealth to dedicate servants to these tasks.
Climate, illumination and ventilation.  Reducing the surface area of a building relative to its size makes it easier to heat, but makes it much harder to cool, ventilate and illuminate.  Remember, this is a village, not a castle built on the taxes of an entire region - the cost of the materials making this building cannot be more than the cost of the materials used to make the multiple buildings that make up a "normal" village or it is unaffordable.  Less surface area gives less area for windows for illumination.  The lack of natural light creates a reliance on artificial light - ie candles or lamps - for interior rooms which makes the ventilation even more difficult and increases the economic cost of living this way.
Defensive posture.  Castles had walls around them that protected not just the central keep but also the outbuildings, water supply (eg well), some livestock and so on, since without these the keep would not last long at all.  The same situation applies to a village - if they need fortifications such as a wall then those must cover the outbuildings with the chickens, cows, well etc.  Given that a wall is required then it does not increase the size significantly to put it around multiple buildings rather than a single large building.

Unless all of the above issues can be addressed, a one-building-village is simply infeasible - it would be much more difficult to maintain, more expensive and less safe to live in than a village consisting of multiple buildings.

Taos Pueblo is another one building village. But in that apparently one building, each house is separate with no interior connections between houses.
Why did the pueblo building culture develop? There are several factors. These include frequent raiding by hostile groups, a culture where men dominate significant parts of society, and religious functions needing plazas. Earlier, when Chaco dominated the region, a lot of small, one family houses were scattered all over. When Chaco fell, many people moved into cliff houses such as Mesa Verde which could be defended.
In many cultures, women often demand their own house.

It's on a hill.
I.e. the answer to the question is that it was done this way to solve a problem they themselves created.
The first building was placed at the top - good view and shelter against a vertical cliff. Seemed like a great idea at the time.
During rain, the run-off from the roof tended to create flowing groundwater downhill of the first building.
Buildings were naturally added to the side to continue the roof uninterrupted going down the hill parallel to the ground. This prevented run-off from flooding the subsequent buildings. Of course, it required a bit of digging to make the floors stepped - but at least they were dry.
Whilst none of the dwellings would have windows, there would be rudimentary chimneys which would allow some little light in and smoke out. If they're clever, then they might come-up with a sort of half-horizontal chimney whereby the fire is lit at the lowest dwelling and the hot smoke will pass through and heat them (in that row) all the way to the top - a bit like a Dragon Kiln but not that hot.

Viking Longhouses were used to house village-like populations. This means you can house many people with limited building materials. The layout is long and thin with no load bearing internal partitions so you could squeeze in an extra family.

Such a structure does exist - Derinkuyu underground city in Turkey. It has been used as shelter from invaders since its construction (or more precisely carving) between 8th to 7th century BC, and several times until early 20th century. It is a multi-story cave system carved in the soft basalt. It sheltered close to 20,000 people along with their livestock, had deep ventillation vents, featured industrial zones of its era (winery, crafts, shops, etc...) and was even connected by tunnels to Kaymakli, another underground city!
The motive for building the city was frequent invasions. In other cities, like Whittier, Alaska, the motive is the harsh climate. You can definitely base your story upon one of these motives. One downside (in a pre-industrial society) is the lack of agriculture at these depths. Your characters must find a way to venture out and work the fields, and the presence of fields will make their enemies wonder where the inhabitants are and search for them. You may conceive a long tunnel connecting the city to distant food sources, like a field or emerging from underground inside a building in another village, hence fooling the enemy for much longer. The inhabitants may be able to trade their crafts for food and sustain themselves.
